# NSRangeExeception

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios-simulator, xcode4.2

My log says that my app is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

```
if (sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) !=SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
        }
```

How would I be able to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure your issue is with that section of code? If you comment it out, do you still get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed the offending line the only array that could be empty is your `char` array `sqlStatement`. Make sure it is properly defined and contains what you expect.